# Update HashMap without adding new entry

Tags: java, hashmap

My program uses two HashmMap and they have exactly the same number of entries and the same keys.
One (tableMap) is static and never changes. The other one is dynamic (partitionMap), this means that I need to update values.
My algorithm got a problem, because seems to be adding one more entry when it is supposed to be not.

```
//I have a LinkedList of strings that I want to add to the HashMap partitionMap
LinkedList<String> partition = new LinkedList<String>();
    for (TerminalNode terminalNode : ctx.U()) {
        partition.add(terminalNode.getText());
    }     
//for each entry of tableMap
for(Entry<String, LinkedList<String>> entry : tableMap.entrySet())
    {
        //I retrieve keys and values from tableMap
        String key = entry.getKey();
        LinkedList<String> attributes = entry.getValue();

        //the condition: if my linkedlist is included in the other do...
        if(attributes.containsAll(partition))
        {
            //get the list of values
            ArrayList<LinkedList<String>> l = partitionMap.get(key);
            //but the first time is always null since I init partitionMap without values
            if(l==null)
            {
                ArrayList<LinkedList<String>> firstLL = new ArrayList<LinkedList<String>>();
                firstLL.add(partition);
                partitionMap.put(key, firstLL); //BUG HERE! add one more entry instead of just updating values
            }
            else
            {
                l.add(partition);
                partitionMap.put(key, l);
            }
        }
    }
```

Does anybody have an idea why this is wrong?

Comment: "seems to be adding" - what does "seems" mean? How do you know it added an extra entry? What is the extra entry?

Comment: *"BUG HERE! add one more entry instead of just updating values"* This doesn't make sense. Either you use a different key, then you get a *new* entry. If you use the same key, then you update it. So you should know if the key is new or not. So the part *"the same keys"* in the first sentence seems to be wrong.

Comment: All right! During the init step the key was assigned in the wrong way.